# import components from create-react-library subfolder

Tags: reactjs, components

I have been trying to use create-react-library and so far it works, but I can only import components successfully from index.js. If I try to make another file , I recieve an import error.

The file structure is as such

```
example
  \ Node Module
  \ public 
  \ src
     | App.js
     | index.js
      ...
src
  \ Patterns
  | index.js
  | button.js
```

Currently I can only successfully import components from index.js of the main src. Is there a way to successfully import components from folders such as Patterns or another file?

\ App.js ( example ) 
Importing button gives me an error "Cant import button from neo"

```
import React from 'react'

import { ExampleComponent,Button} from 'neo'
import {Test} from 'neo/Patterns';


import 'neo/dist/index.css'

const App = () => {
  return (
  <>
  <Test />
  <Button text='Click me' />
   <ExampleComponent text="Create React Library Example " />
  </>
  )
}

export default App
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check if this is what you're trying to achieve.

`index.js` will be exporting required components like this,

```
import ExampleComponent from './ExampleComponent/ExampleComponent';
// ExampleComponent is placed inside a folder named ExampleComponent

import Patterns from './Patterns/Patterns';
// Patterns is placed inside a folder named Patterns

export { ExampleComponent, Patterns };
```

`Patterns.js` can look like this,

```
import React from 'react'

const Patterns = () => {
  return <div>Patterns Component sample</div>
}

export default Patterns;
```

`ExampleComponent.js` can look like this,

```
import React from 'react'
import styles from './styles.module.css'

const ExampleComponent = ({ text }) => {
  return <div className={styles.test}>Example Component: {text}</div>
}

export default ExampleComponent;
```

In the consumer level (in this case, example folder), in any jsx, like `App.js` you can refer those exported components like,

```
import { ExampleComponent, Patterns } from 'neo'

return (
 <Patterns />
)
```